# Where does Xcode save preprocessor macro settings

Tags: xcode, preprocessor

I am working on a project that was created using cmake. (It's a project that is built for lots of different platforms, including Linux Mac OS, and now iOS.)

The cmake process creates an Xcode project which I then am modifying manually.

One of the things the project contains is dozens of preprocessor macros that drive #ifdefs in the code.

The cmake tool only defines these macros for debug builds. I need to build a release version so I can profile the project. however, the release build fails because of missing preprocessor macros, which cause the #ifdef/#ifndef compiler directives to be set wrong.

I'd really rather not manually enter 35 preprocessor settings, especially since the Xcode editor displays this awkward popup with + and - buttons to add/remove one at a time, and when I'm editing release symbols, I can't see the debug symbols, and copy/paste doesn't work.

What I really want to do is find the internal file in the xcode project that sets these macros, copy it out of the debug settings, and either paste it into the release version, or at the very least, manually enter one macro at a time into the release version by copying it from a textfile containing the macros that were defined in the debug version.

Can somebody tell me where the debug and release preprocessor macros are saved in the Xcode project file hierarchy so I can go read the raw file and possibly modify it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your project.pbxproj Build Settings, search for GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS.  That should be a list of the macros.  It should be pretty easy to copy and paste the list from one configuration to the other.

Comment: Cool. Thanks. Sadly I had to manually retype all of the definitions for my release build, but I will remember this for next time.